# babel-preset-es2015: No compatible version found: babel-helper-hoist-variables@^6.6.5

Tags: node.js, babeljs

I recently pulled from an old boiler that I wrote, and tried to npm install, but I keep getting the listed error when the install hits 'babel-preset-es2015':

```
npm ERR! Darwin 15.3.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "i"
npm ERR! node v5.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.6.0

npm ERR! No compatible version found: babel-helper-hoist-variables@^6.6.5
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! 6.6.4, 6.5.0, 6.5.0-1, 6.3.13, 6.2.4, 6.1.18, 6.1.17, 6.1.16, 6.1.13, 6.1.12, 6.1.10, 6.1.9, 6.1.8, 6.1.7, 6.1.6, 6.1.5, 6.0.15, 6.0.14, 6.0.2, 6.0.0
```

Does anyone know how I can get around this bug? I tried updating all of my babel dependencies, upgrading node, reinstalling npm -- but I haven't been able to get rid of this error. Is there some issue with babel-preset-es2015 and my node environment?

The full boiler is at https://github.com/breezykermo/react-redux-boiler, to see package.json and other potentially relevant files.

Thanks!

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm getting the same error but it's complaining about `babel-preset-es2015`

Answer (score 0):

You likely have an npm cache that has not properly updated itself. The most recent version of that package is definitely `6.6.5` which matches that version range.